# File downloaded from blob loses its tag braces

Tags: javascript, html, blob

To download an HTML file generated by a script on client side, from a blob, the following code is used. The text is taken from a textarea, processed and then sent to the blob.

```
var html_text = document.getElementById("textarea1").innerHTML;
/* the textarea contains tags like <b>test</b> */
var blob = new Blob([html_text], {
 type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = "new.html";
a.href = url;
a.textContent = "Download";
document.getElementById("aDiv").appendChild(a);
```

When the download link is clicked, however, I get a file with HTML entities inside like "gt; lt;" etc. where tag braces are wanted. What is my mistake?

Comment: I tried in Chrome with success, braces intact in html file

Comment: Thank you. I see, I have to improve the question. It's incomplete, let me show a bit more info about my issue.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly, except that the generated file is blank. I just replaced `.innerHTML` to `.value` at `var html_text = document.getElementById("textarea1").innerHTML;`

Comment: Thank you, Yogesh. The 'value' thing made this work. Could you make this comment an answer, then I will choose it.